# .Net Core API - oData Prefix is lost when passing arguments

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, odata, asp.net-core-routing

This call works correctly and is mapped to /oData/Projects.

```
[HttpGet(Name = "GetProjects")]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IEnumerable<ProjectEntity> Get()
    {
        return _db.Projects;
    }
```

How can I make pass an argument with out losing the oData prefix in the URL?

This loses the oData Prefix:

```
[HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetProjectById")]
    [EnableQuery]
    public ProjectEntity GetProjectById(int id)
    {
        return _db.Projects.Where(p => p.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

I am using .net core web api and oData 8.0

Here is the full controller:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class ProjectsController : ControllerBase
{       
    private readonly ILogger<ProjectsController> _logger;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    public ProjectsController(ILogger<ProjectsController> logger, ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _logger = logger;
       _db = db;
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetProjectById")]
    [EnableQuery]
    public ProjectEntity GetProjectById(int id)
    {
        return _db.Projects.Where(p => p.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    [HttpGet(Name = "GetProjects")]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IEnumerable<ProjectEntity> Get()
    {
        return _db.Projects;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Tom is there any progress on the issue? Feel free to share your concern.

Answer (score 0):

> To enable OData attribute routing to work, either in `controller` or
> `action` should decorate an attribute named `ODataRoutingAttribute`.
> It’s renamed as `ODataAttributeRoutingAttribute in 8.0.` since as you
> are using `asp.net core` controller so your `controller action` should
> be like below:

**`Model:`**

```
public class ProjectInfo
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ApiVersion { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
    }
```

**`Controller:`**

```
public class ProjectsController : ControllerBase
    {
        private ProjectInfo[] project= new ProjectInfo[]
        {
            new ProjectInfo
            {
                Id = 1,
                ApiVersion = "v1.0",
                Name = "Kiron",
                PhoneNumber = "111-222-3333"
            },
            new ProjectInfo
            {
                Id = 2,
                ApiVersion = "v1.0",
                Name = "Farid",
                PhoneNumber = "456-ABC-8888"
            }
        };

        [EnableQuery]
        [HttpGet("odata/Projects")]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            return Ok(project);
        }

        [ODataAttributeRoutingAttribute]
        [HttpGet("odata/Projects/{key}")]
        public IActionResult Get(int key)
        {
            var project = project.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == key);
            if (project == null)
            {
                return NotFound($"Cannot find project with Id={key}.");
            }

            return Ok(project);
        }
    }
```

> **`Note:`** You can also set `[ODataAttributeRoutingAttribute]` on global controller so that you don't need to set on each action. in
> that case just get rid of `[ApiController]` and
> `[Route("[controller]")]`

**`Reference Required:`**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData.Routing.Attributes;
```

**`Startup.cs:`**

```
 services.AddControllers().AddOData(opt => opt.Select());
```

**`Output:`**

[image]

> **`Note:`** As you are using `oData 8.0` you have to use `ODataAttributeRoutingAttribute` annotations either on your
> `controller` or `action` as you can see the above code and screenshot.
> It will resolve your problem.

In addition you could have a look more details on our [official blog document here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/odata/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-core-odata-8-0-rc/#attribute-routing-using-http-verb-attributes) also here is the [sample project](https://github.com/kironiitdu/-kironiitdu-Odata8RoutingPrefix)

Comment: Thanks Md Farrid, but you still lose the oData prefix with these code snippets.

if the default behavior is that the oData syntax will stay /oData/Projects.

I can't get /oData/Projects/{id}

Comment: I have updated my answer, hope it would resolve your issue accordingly. If you still have further concern feel free to share.

Comment: Hey MD, I tried it but it still didn't work for me :/ I think it's because im using oData 8.

Comment: I am also using `Odata 8` I doubt you are missing somewhere. Could you please try the [sample](https://github.com/kironiitdu/-kironiitdu-Odata8RoutingPrefix) and compare with yours one.